# Duplicated tickets. Sentry and Jira integrations

Tags: jira, sentry

We set automatically create JIRA Tickets if sentry issues created. How prevent send tickets if duplicate issues? I have read the documentation but did not find it. can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Sentry will create 1 jira issue for each 1 of its issue. How are you getting duplicates? What do you consider a duplicate issue?

Comment: example: in my code, my requests with "a" parameter, ticket is created. and if re requests with "b" parameter, the ticket is created again. it's redundant because it comes from the same error code

Comment: Do you have two issues in Sentry? It seems the dupe happens not only on JIRA but on Sentry which mirrors its issues with JIRA. You can control grouping through the Fingerprint event property